# Language best for Text Processing

Tags: java, text-processing

I am working on Text Processing Project. Where I need to do many operaition on text provided to me. Like finding substring in the text (Using Regex), deleting garbage text (Using Exact or Regex match), Splitting Text into multiple parts. Currently I am using Java for this purpose. Just want to understand is Java most suitable language for such things or I should use some other language.

Comment: It depends on what are the goals, what are the inputs, how often the code for processing should be modified, what language you already know/like, etc. Can you add more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's opinion based, but I'd say one language is as good as another for this.  There are some great java libraries for text parsing.  I've been using the Guava Joiner, Splitter and Charmatcher classes a lot recently for similar things.  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/